# How to allow only one connection per connection point?

Tags: mxgraph

I'm already using `snapToPoint` so that connections are only possible on the constraints of a vertex. However currently I can connect multiple edges to the same connection point. Is there a built-in way to allow only one connection per connection point?

If no and as I'm new to mxGraph, is there any recommendation on where to put the code in order to get the desired behaviour, e.g. listening to `mxEvent.CELL_CONNECTED` or `mxEvent.CONNECT_CELL`? Or do I have to overwrite/reuse any predefined method like `mxGraph.cellConnected`?

Comment: Did you try the `graph.multigraph = false` property? 
http://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html

Comment: @NickAth Thanks for the advice. I did give it a try but with this option I can still have multiple connection at the same connection point (if connecting with several different vertices). By now I implemented it by myself but it's not a very good solution yet and quiet tedious to handle.

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue, wanting to limit the number of connections to a connection constraint.

I ended up removing connection constraints that already have an edge connected them

10-02-2021 update: found a better way:

```
graph.getAllConnectionConstraints = function (terminal) {
    if (terminal != null && this.model.isVertex(terminal.cell)) {
      // connection points: North, East, South, West
      var allConnectionConstraints = [
        new mxConnectionConstraint(new mxPoint(0.5, 0), true),
        new mxConnectionConstraint(new mxPoint(1, 0.5), true),
        new mxConnectionConstraint(new mxPoint(0.5, 1), true),
        new mxConnectionConstraint(new mxPoint(0, 0.5), true)
      ];

      let result = allConnectionConstraints;

      // Remove the ones that have an edge connected to them
      if (terminal.cell.edges) {
        terminal.cell.edges.forEach((edge) => {
          const edgeState = this.view.getState(edge);
          const source = edge.source.id === terminal.cell.id;
          const edgeConnectionConstraint = graph.getConnectionConstraint(
            edgeState,
            terminal,
            source
          );

          // edgeConnectionConstraint does not include name property
          const itemToDelete = result.find(
            (item) =>
              item.dx === edgeConnectionConstraint.dx &&
              item.dy === edgeConnectionConstraint.dy &&
              item.point.equals(edgeConnectionConstraint.point)
          );
          if (itemToDelete) {
            result = result.filter((x) => x !== itemToDelete);
          }
          result.removeAll(
            (item) =>
              item.dx === edgeConnectionConstraint.dx &&
              item.dy === edgeConnectionConstraint.dy &&
              item.point.equals(edgeConnectionConstraint.point)
          );
        });
      }

      return result;
    }

    return null;
  };
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/mxgraph-react-example-forked-uwru4

below is original post...

```
  var graph = this.graph;
  this.graph.getAllConnectionConstraints = function (terminal) {
    if (terminal != null && this.model.isVertex(terminal.cell)) {

      // connection points: North, East, South, West
      var allConnectionConstraints = [new mxConnectionConstraint(new mxPoint(.5, 0), true),
      new mxConnectionConstraint(new mxPoint(1, .5), true),
      new mxConnectionConstraint(new mxPoint(.5, 1), true),
      new mxConnectionConstraint(new mxPoint(0, .5), true)];

      var result = [];

      // loop through all connection constraints
      allConnectionConstraints.forEach(connectionConstraint => {
        var add = true;

        // see if an edge is already connected to this constraint
        if (terminal && terminal.cell && terminal.cell.edges) {
          terminal.cell.edges.forEach(edge => {
            var edgeStyle = graph.getCellStyle(edge);
            var edgeX = -1;
            var edgeY = -1;

            // is this edge comming in or going out?
            if (edge.source.id === terminal.cell.id) {
              // going out
              edgeX = edgeStyle.exitX;
              edgeY = edgeStyle.exitY;
            } else if (edge.target.id === terminal.cell.id) {
              // comming in
              edgeX = edgeStyle.entryX;
              edgeY = edgeStyle.entryY;
            }

            if (connectionConstraint.point.x === edgeX &&
              connectionConstraint.point.y === edgeY) {
              // already a connection to this connectionConstraint, do not add to result
              add = false;
            }
          });
        }

        if (add) {
          result.push(connectionConstraint);
        }
      });

      // return all connectionConstraints for this terminal that do not already have a connection
      return result;
    }

    return null;
  };
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/mxgraph-react-example-4ox9f